# Should we, and if so where, post solutions to problems if we use a solution which isn't one of the answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

If you ask a question such as the following:

> How can I design some feature X so
>   that it is Y, and supports Z?

(e.g. [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12529/a-component-based-entity-system-with-user-friendliness-in-mind))

Obviously at some point you're going to work out how you did it. Since this is designed as a site to learn, I think posting the solution you used (if it differs from the answers given) could be useful to other people. I'm not suggesting posting your solution and accepting it; I'm saying to accept the suggestion that was most useful and put yours as a tool for others to learn from.

However, is this more suited to be posted as an answer to your question, or edited in as a 'Here's how I went with it' end to the question itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think posting your solution as an answer is the more "correct" way to go about it, so that the masses can vote on a solution (up or down) depending on how good of an answer it is.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an answer to the question as stated, I recommend posting it as an answer.

If the nature of the question changed somewhat in the process of discovering your solution, I recommend posting it as an edit.